# mod_rewrite - replace word or character in url

Tags: mod-rewrite

Am trying to mod_rewrite a URL, but unfortunately without any luck.

http://mywebsite.com/gallery/mycustom-gallery/linkid417

Should be changed to:

http://mywebsite.com/gallery/mycustom-gallery/#417

Where '417' is a dynamic id of an image & `mycustom-gallery` will also change every-time.

I've tried the following rules, but none seems to work...

```
   RewriteRule ^/gallery/$1/#([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/y/([0-9]+)$ /gallery/$1/linkid [L,R=301]
RewriteRule mycustom-gallery/#.*$ /mycustom-gallery/linkid=417/$1
```

Regards,
Charl

Comment: Which way are you looking to do the rewrite? From http://mywebsite.com/gallery/mycustom-gallery/linkid417 to http://mywebsite.com/gallery/mycustom-gallery/#417 (as your question suggest) or vice versa (as your rewrite is written)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to rewrite from http://mywebsite.com/gallery/mycustom-gallery/linkid417 to http://mywebsite.com/gallery/mycustom-gallery/#417 you can do it as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^/gallery/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/linkid([0-9]+)$ /gallery/$1/#$2 [NE,L,R=301]
```

The `NE|noescape` flag prevents Apache from escaping the hash in the URL during the 301 redirect.

If however you wish to do the opposite, i.e. redirect from http://mywebsite.com/gallery/mycustom-gallery/#417 to http://mywebsite.com/gallery/mycustom-gallery/linkid417, that cannot be done, as the fragment part of the request ("#417") is not passed to Apache along with the request as per [RFC1808](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1808.txt).

Comment: Hi All

Thanks for all the responses.

The following did the trick....

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/gallery/mycustom-gallery/[a-z]+([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /gallery/mycustom-gallery/\%23%1 [R=301,NE,L]

And then changed %23 to #.

Regards,
Charl

Comment: That solution will only work for URLs containing "mycustom-gallery". If the gallery name can change, you need to use a regexp pattern to match that as well.